# Average function on different columns in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, aggregate-functions, hue, bigdata

I want to find the average of 3 columns using hive query.
Consider the below data:
[image: Sample Data]

I need to find the average marks scored by each student and then the average of total marks in each school:
NULL should be ignored.

My output should look like this:

[image]

Can you guys help me out here

Comment: Uh, which output are you trying to get?  You have two candidates.

Comment: Please post data in formatted text, not images; this will help people in building an example to work on. You can even have a look at [MCVE] to improve your question

Comment: First i need to find the average marks scored by each student in each school.Then i need to get the average of marks in individual schools(School A and School B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive should automatically ignore `NULL` values on aggregates as reported [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-362).

For readability, I suggest using `COALESCE` instead of `IF IS NULL` statements such as: `COALESCE(Math,0) as Math`

Answer (score 0):

Average of each student:

```
select school,SL_No,Name,Math,Phy,Chem,(if(Math is NULL,0,Math)+if(Phy is NULL,0,Phy)+if(Chem is NULL,0,Chem))/3 as avg_marks from my_table
```

Average Marks of each school

```
select school,avg(avg_marks) from (select school,SL_No,Name,Math,Phy,Chem,(if(Math is NULL,0,Math)+if(Phy is NULL,0,Phy)+if(Chem is NULL,0,Chem))/3 as avg_marks from my_table
) temp group by school
```